# EPPLUS COPY RANGE to destination stops working when upgrading beyond v. 5.7.5. Has anyone else seen this problem?

Tags: vb.net, epplus

This is the code, which works in 5.7.5 but not later.

```
Public Shared Sub PopulateXlsm(Filein As FileInfo, Fileout As FileInfo)

    Dim src As ExcelWorksheet, tgt As ExcelWorksheet
    Dim srcEndRow As Integer, tgtStartRow As Integer
    Dim newFile As String

    newFile = Fileout.Directory.ToString & "\" & Filein.Name
    If Dir(newFile) <> "" Then
        MsgBox("File: " & Filein.Name & " already exists in output directory")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Using wbIn = New ExcelPackage(Filein)
        Using wbout = New ExcelPackage(Fileout)
            src = wbIn.Workbook.Worksheets(0)
            tgt = wbout.Workbook.Worksheets(0)

            ' This subroutine will copy completed ledger file(s) into combined ledger 
              transaction file
            ' find first blank record in target to write new records to
            tgtStartRow = NextRow(tgt, "", 4)
            srcEndRow = src.Dimension.Rows ' last line incl totals

            ' copy the new records from source to destination

            src.Cells(4, 1, srcEndRow, 17).Copy(tgt.Cells("A" & tgtStartRow + 1))

            wbIn.Save()
            wbout.Save()
            ' all done!
        End Using
    End Using
    'move file to new directory
    Filein.MoveTo(Fileout.Directory.ToString & "\" & Filein.Name)

End Sub
```

The error occurs when attempting the cells.copy line. Downgrade back to 5.7.5 and the program runs properly again. The error message is:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Specified argument was out of the
> range of valid values. Parameter name: Start cell Address must be less
> or equal to End cell address'
>
> This is thrown in "OfficeOpenXml.ExcelAddressBase.Validate()"

Comment: Amend your question with the error message

Comment: Error message added to question